# Use bluetooth beacon or NFC Tag to sideload android app

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, ibeacon, sideloading

I want to sideload an android app via bluetooth (NFC would also be ok). My basic idea is, that you go near a beacon or NFC Tag and it will ask you to install an application and finally sends it to your phone. It has to have a capacity of around 2MB and shouldn't be too expensive (same range as BT Beacons or NFC Tags). I wonder, if there is a simple solution available. It should work completely offline, thats the big problem. My app is a navigation app, that works completely offline for a certain area. People will only know about the app, if they see some sign and a beacon / NFC Tag nearby. So they cant download it beforehand. Do you guys have any idea? Beacons are not used to store data and only got max. 250KB Flash Memory. NFC Tags got like 7KB so I'm at a loss of ideas right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think beacons only work on already running apps. Not sure about NFC.

Comment: NFC Tags can send some Sring data, open a browser and so on. But nothing that would help me, like sending an app, because its memory is only about the mentioned 7KB. Ok, so thats what I'm also finding on the web - you need an app for those beacons.

Comment: So you've done your research and you know it's not possible. I'm not sure what you need from us. You are indeed completely correct. It's not possible.

Comment: If NFC tags can do that, could you open a browser to a mirror to download the app?

Comment: I'm asking if there is some other but similar way to do this. I might not have thought of everything. Yes, NFC Tags could do that BinaryJudy, but still i'd be in need of mobile net or WiFi connection.

Comment: You'll need to create your own hotspot or wifi network. It doesn't matter if your hotspot is not connected to the internet, as long as it can create a LAN for other phones to connect to.

Comment: By the way, your navigation app doesn't seem very big at all. Isn't it just a map? If it's just a map, you could just suggest that people take a picture of your map with their cell phone.

Comment: Yes, hotspot might be a possibility, but not that practical. I want to be able to put the Tag or Beacon or Whatever just anywhere. The Navigation App is not that big, because it only works locally at a certain area. The app including everything for a certain area is around 2MB. So i could put a tag every x meter that holds the app. And its more than a map. It parses openstreetmap files and runs a navigation algorithm over the created nodes. Then it shows the route on the map (.pgn files).